# How to save jar file from h2o MOJO download with custom name?

Tags: python, h2o

In Python, while downloading MOJO file from h2o, how to rename the jar file.
if I run below code, the zip file and jar of the model being saved,

```
modelfile = model.download_mojo(path="c:/models/", get_genmodel_jar=True)
```

but model file is not saved, I have to save it separately using h2o.save_model

```
rf_path = h2o.save_model(model=model, path="c:/models/", force=True)
```

jar file name is saving as "h2o-genmodel.jar"

I want to rename the jar file while saving, I tried below code, this saves the zip file and model file, Not the jar file

```
modelfile = model.download_mojo(path="c:/models/", get_genmodel_jar=True, genmodel_name = "my_jar")
```

Is this an issue?

I except to rename my jar file?
And If I can save zip, model and jar file in one go may be better?